Transit visa requirements for a layover in London Heathrow airport?
As an Indian passport holder. I will be flying with British Airways on a round trip from Sweden to India. During my journey, I have a layover at London Heathrow Airport, and my connecting flight is in the same terminal.
Here are the key points:
Layover details:
Airport: London Heathrow
Connecting flight: British Airways (in the same terminal)
Immigration control:
Since my connecting flight is in the same terminal, I understand that I may not need to pass through UK border control. However, I would appreciate confirmation from your end.
Transit visa:
I hold a valid Sweden student residence permit card. Could you please clarify whether my residence permit card exempts me from needing a transit visa for the UK?
